# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir una cantidad de números si el punto de inicio es mayor a la condición de permanencia de una repetición utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bucle-for, condiciones, while

¡Hola! Quería imprimir los números enteros desde el 30 al 10, pero no sé cómo se aplicaría esto si el punto de inicio es mayor a la condición de permanencia.

En este caso decidí usar la estructura *while*:

```
let entero = 30;

while(entero <= 10){
    console.log(`${entero}`);
    entero++;
}
```

¿Que estaría mal con lo anterior?

Comment: Si vas de mas a menos, tendras que comprobar que el entero sea >= 10 y en cada iteración en vez de sumar uno, restas 1.

Comment: Ah, tiene sentido. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Te animo a que cuando lo resuelvas, escribas una respuesta a tu propia pregunta indicando cómo lo has resuelto para así ayudar a otra persona que encuentre tu pregunta en el futuro.

Comment: Claro, tienes razón. Ya está publicado, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolución:

```
let entero = 30;

while(entero >= 10){
    $("#pResultado").append(`${entero} <br>`);
    entero = entero - 1;
}
```

Comment: Así como usabas `entero++;` para incrementar en 1 la variable, tambien podes usar `entero--;` para decrementar en 1 la variable.